# AWS Cognito logout using spring security logoutSuccessHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I face an issue with the logout functionality(integrate with AWS Cognito), I hope someone will help me in identifying the root cause. My requirement is to redirect the user back to the login screen and prompt for username and password once the user clicks on logout and invalidate the session. But I am getting these errors while I click on the logout link because of the redirection happening.

---

(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://incatalyst.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=******&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=STATE' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/logout') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
jquery.js:8623 GET https://incatalyst.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=39ebrskq9ne4ib97466cav9fpf&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=STATE net::ERR_FAILED

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


      @Autowired
      CustomizeLogoutSuccessHandler customizeLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Map<String, Object> user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {
        System.out.println(principal);
        return Collections.singletonMap("name", principal.getAttribute("name"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                .antMatchers("/","/logout", "/error", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .exceptionHandling(e -> e
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            )
            .csrf(c -> c
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            )
            .logout(l -> l
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customizeLogoutSuccessHandler).permitAll()
            )
            .oauth2Login();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }



}
```

Below is my customizeLogoutSuccessHandler

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomizeLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler{



      @Override
      public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
          throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Code For Business Here
     //   System.out.println("Logout Sucessfull with Principal: " + authentication.getName());

          Cookie awsCookie = new Cookie("AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0", "deleted");
            awsCookie.setMaxAge(-1);
            awsCookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(awsCookie);
            request.getSession().invalidate();
            //redirect to login
          response.sendRedirect("https://incatalyst.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=*****&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=STATE");
         response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET");   

            response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
      }

}
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>Demo</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<base href="/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="container unauthenticated">
        With Cognito: <a href="/oauth2/authorization/cognito">click here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container authenticated" style="display: none">
        Logged in as: <span id="user"></span>
        <div>
            <button onClick="logout()"  class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="/webjars/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $
              .ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
                  if (settings.type == 'POST' || settings.type == 'PUT'
                      || settings.type == 'DELETE') {

                    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/
                        .test(settings.url))) {
                      // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN",
                          Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
          $.get("/user", function(data) {
            $("#user").html(data.name);
            $(".unauthenticated").hide();
            $(".authenticated").show();
          });
          var logout = function() {
            $.post("/logout", function() {
              $("#user").html('');
              $(".unauthenticated").show();
              $(".authenticated").hide();
            })
            return true;
          }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you have a solution ?